# Microcontroller - Button 'holding down' listener

Tags: c++, microcontroller

I am working with a Texas Instruments LauncherPad MSP432 P401R and Energia.
I am trying to write a small program that counts the times I press button2 while I keep button1 pressed down.

```
int push1_listener = -1;
int push2_listener = -1;
int digit = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(PUSH1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(PUSH2, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  push1_listener = digitalRead(PUSH1);
  push2_listener = digitalRead(PUSH2);
  while(push1_listener == 0) {
    if(push2_listener == 0) {
      digit++;
      delay(200);
      Serial.print("btn2");
    }
    Serial.print("btn1");
  }
}
```

The program goes into the while loop, I can see the "btn1" in the Serial console. However the program does not go into the if case.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  Maybe use an In-Circuit Emulator (ICE).  You could use a JTAG debugger or maybe some remote debugging utility.

Comment: What are the units of time for the `delay` function?

Comment: Okay. Milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads the status of both push buttons once before entering the while loop.  Then it never reads the push button status within the while loop.  So the value of the push button variables will never change within the while loop.  You need to re-read the push button status repeatedly within the while loop.

Maybe something like this:

```
while ((push1_listener = digitalRead(PUSH1)) == 0) {
    push2_listener = digitalRead(PUSH2);
    if (push2_listener == 0) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: And I would add that if you want to count **the times** you depress a button, you should count the transitions from 1 to 0. To do this, you need a variable more to remember the state of the button, and keep polling. When variable is different than button, something is happened - look what is happened, update the variable, and continue to poll.

Comment: Thank you very much @kkrambo!
And thanks for the advice @linuxfan!